# Is it possible to store a queue-like structure in Django database?

Tags: django

This might be a stupid question, but I'm new to databases and I could't find an answer anywhere.
Is it possible to somehow store a FIFO queue in django? Some equivalent of python's collections.deque? Let's say I hypothetically have a model AverageRate, which stores a queue of up to 24 numbers and an average value of those numbers: (sum(numbers) / len (numbers)).

```
class AverageRate:
    last_24_numbers = # FIFO queue up to 24 elements long
    average_value = # average value of last_24_numbers
```

Every hour a function adds a new number to last_24_numbers and calculates average value. If the queue reaches 24 elements, then to append a new element to the end of the queue, it must pop the oldest element from the beginning of the queue.

Honestly the only solution I came up with was to possibly convert the queue to string and store it in CharField, and then convert it back every time I need to use it. But I dunno... it just feels like not the best idea. I would obviously want to use the most efficient solution.

Comment: Use an extra model `AverageRateItem`, *don't* store the average explicitly.

Comment: But why though?

Comment: because storing data aggregates (or data duplication) is often a source of evil: even on the same database, keeping data in sync turns out to be a serious challenge

Comment: Should I convert the queue to string or try to use PostgreSQL's array field instead?

Comment: no! array fields, and JSON blobs and all these all violate first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: So is storing a string of a list a better solution? It will need processing power to convert it back and forth.

Comment: It is better to just store these as indepdent records.

Comment: Oh, you mean turn every added number into an object? That could do the job, thanks.